# Using calculation in Case Statement - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Hi sql wizards and sorcerers,

I am trying to work out SLA days based on a particular parameter (case-type). For each case type, the SLA days are worked out slightly differently. My question is: do I use CASE STATEMENT to achieve this? I'll put down what I have so far, which isn't working:

```
fifthlevel --with statement declaring sla days
AS (SELECT

     CASE sla_days
     WHEN fourthlevel.case_type = 'Complaint'
     THEN sla_days =

      ( SELECT COUNT (*)
        FROM (SELECT business_date
              FROM ( SELECT TO_DATE ('01-01-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy') + LEVEL - 1
                               business_date
                     FROM DUAL
                     CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                                 TO_DATE ('31-12-2099', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
                               - TO_DATE ('01-01-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
                               + 1) date_tab1
                     WHERE TO_CHAR (business_date, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
                     AND business_date NOT IN (SELECT holiday_dt
                                               FROM cisadm.ci_cal_hol
                                               WHERE calendar_cd = 'WAW01'
                                              )
                   ) work_days1
             WHERE work_days1.business_date > fourthlevel.correspondence_date
             AND work_days1.business_date <= fourthlevel.close_date
             )
     WHEN fourthlevel.case_type = 'Enquiry'
     THEN sla_days = (SELECT COUNT (*)
                      FROM (SELECT business_date
                            FROM (SELECT TO_DATE ('01-01-2011',
                                                   'dd-mm-yyyy')
                                            + LEVEL
                                            - 1
                                               business_date
                                   FROM DUAL
                                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <=TO_DATE('31-12-2099',
                                                                'dd-mm-yyyy')
                                                      TO_DATE('01-01-2011',
                                                              'dd-mm-yyyy')+ 1
                                  ) date_tab1
                            WHERE TO_CHAR (business_date, 'DY') 
                                  NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
                             AND business_date 
                                  NOT IN (SELECT holiday_dt
                                          FROM cisadm.ci_cal_hol
                                          WHERE calendar_cd = 'WAW01'
                                         )
                            ) work_days1
                      WHERE work_days1.business_date > fourthlevel.agreed_Date
                        AND work_days1.business_date <=
                               fourthlevel.close_date
                     )
     END
    FROM fourthlevel,

    fourthlevel.* --also wanting to select * from preceding WITH statement
    FROM fourthlevel)
```

Ok so that looks a bit messy but essentially I am trying to get two different calculations based on the case_types of 'Complaint' and 'Enquiry'.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Let me know if I can provide any further information.

Legends!

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the replies, I am sorry I am not able to upvote yet.

Also wondering if I would use CASE if i wanted to have a field that specified whether the sla days were within threshold. Ie, one field that indicates whether sla_days are under 15 and another field that indicates whether sla_days are under 20. 

It would be something like: 

`case when sla_days <=15 then 'Under SLA" 
WHEN sla_days > 15 then 'Exceeds SLA' `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract work_days1 subquery as a separate cte:

```
, work_days1 as (
SELECT business_date
       FROM (    SELECT TO_DATE ('01-01-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy') + LEVEL - 1
                           business_date
                   FROM DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                             TO_DATE ('31-12-2099', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
                           - TO_DATE ('01-01-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
                           + 1) date_tab1
      WHERE     TO_CHAR (business_date, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
            AND business_date NOT IN (SELECT holiday_dt
                                        FROM cisadm.ci_cal_hol
                                       WHERE calendar_cd = 'WAW01')),
fifthlevel --with statement declaring sla days
 AS (SELECT
 CASE 
 WHEN fourthlevel.case_type = 'Complaint'
 THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM work_days1 WHERE
 work_days1.business_date > fourthlevel.correspondence_date
    AND work_days1.business_date <= fourthlevel.close_date)
 WHEN fourthlevel.case_type = 'Enquiry'
 THEN sla_days = (SELECT COUNT (*) work_days1 WHERE
 work_days1.business_date > fourthlevel.agreed_Date
                    AND work_days1.business_date <=
                           fourthlevel.close_date) END as sla_days, * 
      FROM fourthlevel)
```

Comment: Your solution is also great for when I need to use completely different calculations for each case type. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only difference between the two case_type's is the condition of `work_days1.business_date`. So, you can condense the query, as follows:

```
fifthlevel --with statement declaring sla days
AS (
SELECT
  COUNT (*) sla_days
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      business_date
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          TO_DATE ('01-01-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy') + LEVEL- 1 business_date
        FROM
          DUAL
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TO_DATE ('31-12-2099','dd-mm-yyyy') - TO_DATE ('01-01-2011','dd-mm-yyyy') + 1
      )
      date_tab1
    WHERE TO_CHAR (business_date, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
    AND business_date NOT IN (SELECT holiday_dt FROM cisadm.ci_cal_hol WHERE calendar_cd = 'WAW01')
  )
  work_days1 INNER JOIN fourthlevel
ON
  work_days1.business_date > (
    CASE
      WHEN fourthlevel.case_type = 'Complaint' THEN fourthlevel.correspondence_date
      WHEN fourthlevel.case_type = 'Enquiry' THEN fourthlevel.agreed_Date
    END)
AND work_days1.business_date <= fourthlevel.close_date;
```

Comment: Your solution is perfect what I am after, however it was giving me incorrect sla_days. Removing the inner join and nesting the CASE statement in the WHERE clause fixed it for me. 

What was the reasoning behind creating the inner join?

Comment: I see that `work_days1` and `fourthlevel` are joined using the conditions (e.g. `work_days1.business_date > fourthlevel.agreed_Date`). Therefore, I explicitly created the INNER JOIN.